# Saving the HTML of a Flask web page generated from a form submit gives 400 output

Tags: python, flask

Whenever I try to save the HTML of a web page generated in Flask from a form submission on my local test server, the saved page gives this output:

> Bad Request
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.

I can save other pages of my app with no issue, it is only pages that are submitted through a form.

The snippet of the Flask url route in question, this is hit from a form on another url:

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profile():
    dist_type = request.form['district-select']
    dist_num  = int(request.form['district-number'])
    json_data = {
        'dist_type' : dist_type,
        'dist_num'  : dist_num
    }
    return render_template('profile.html', data = json_data)
```

The HTML template 'profile.html' is filled out with json_data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {{ data|tojson|safe }}        
</script>

<div class="distr-head" id="distr-type">{{data['dist_type']}}</div>
<div class="distr-head" id="distr-num">{{data['dist_num']}}</div>
```

**When I Ctrl + S to save this filled template IN MY BROWSER, or link it to other sites, I cannot access the HTML and instead get a 400 Bad Request**

Comment: @palsch What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Wait, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Ok, with this extra information, my answer is *bad*.

Comment: I think this is probably too localized to be answered, really wish I knew why  I can't access the HTML though...

Comment: No, I am posting form data just fine, it's when I try to SAVE the html page IN MY BROWSER that I get the 400 error.

Comment: No my real code is 1000's lines long.  The template fills out just fine, its when I try to SAVE THE HTML IN MY BROWSER that the saved file is 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.form` is not populated during a GET request, only during POST (and PUT, etc.).  Trying to access a key on `request.form` when it doesn't exist raises a 400 error.  You should guard the code that expects form data so that it only executes during a POST request.

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profile():
    data = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {
            'dist_type': request.form['district-select'],
            'dist_num': int(request.form['district-number'])
        }

    return render_template('profile.html', data=data)
```